# wordwrap + nl2br = more than you need line breaks?

Tags: php, html

I have a textarea inside a form. No wrap in the html code is provided.
In the php file (forms action=phpfile.php) I get the value of the textarea like so:

```
$ad_text=wordwrap(nl2br($_POST['annonsera_text']), 47, '<br>', true);
echo $ad_text;
```

Then the output is:

```
hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohe
llohello.
hi.
hi.
hi.

/> hi.
hi.
hi.
hi.

/>
```

and the original input in the form textarea is like this:

```
hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohe
llohello.
hi.
hi.
hi.
hi.
hi.
hi.
hi.
```

There seem to be a line break after the third \n or so, followed by a '/>'

Any ide why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wordwrap`](http://php.net/wordwrap) doesn't view `<br>` as a linebreak - if you move  `nl2br` after wordwrap it will work as you want, but you should change the wordwrap parameter to "\n" to avoid double-spacing:

```
$ad_text = nl2br(wordwrap($_POST['annonsera_text'], 47, "\n", true));
```

Comment: Without nl2br, whenever the user hits 'enter' and there is a NL, it gets skipped and is dislayed in a long string!

Comment: Ah, you need to run nl2br *after* wordwrap then